# take a photo using webcam with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to take a photo using a webcam from my application. How do I accomplish that? My application is developed in C# and to make a visitor's pass, I want to take a photo of the particular visitor when he enters the company building.

Comment: I  think it's not possible in asp.net/MVC.You have to developed a silverlight(Flash) app for this.

Comment: If you want to develop it in silverlight let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [jQuery Webcam](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/)

I am struggling to get the save function to work, but its a start.

Comment: did you ever get this to work, im struggling with this part as well. I can get the input stream and it appears to have image data, however I can get it to convert to an actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Webcams all use a different API. Find the API that your webcam supports...let me know, and I will happily talk you through how to do it.

I assume that you are talking WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some kind of trusted client side code, if you want to do this. Java, Flash, SilverLight are all possibilities. But they may create a dependency on a particular WebCam/Software/API.

You'd be much better off configuring your web cam to put its photos in a single place and have a web form that accepts a file upload.

This way when your web cam breaks and you can't get the exact same device you don't have to recode.

Comment: "This way when you web cam breaks and you cant get the exact same device you don't have to recode" -- and you don't get blamed for breaking it!